# Python selenium to select "menuitemradio" through parent element

Tags: python, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

The following code keeps giving an **invalid syntax error**.
I think its because of the wrong use of the `recent_rating_bt_2` to access the child elements and don't know how else to go about it.

This the source code I've been working on

[image]

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
menu_bt = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, '//g-dropdown-button[@class=\'dkSGpd NkCsjc\']'))
)
menu_bt.click()
recent_rating_bt = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//g-menu[@role=\'menuitemradio\']')
  [2]recent_rating_bt_2=recent_rating_bt.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class='znKVS' and 
    .='Newest']')

    recent_rating_bt_2.click()
```

Comment: 1) `[2]recent_rating_bt_2` should have a line break after `[2]` 2) you need to escape all `'` in the last selector like you do in the first one.

Comment: Provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Post your code directly, screenshots are discouraged.

Comment: @БогданОпир I wasn't able to, It couldn't be copied.

Comment: You are using single quotes for `znKVS` within another set of single quotes. Use double quotes for one of them.